# Why isn't "/" serving index.html in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a function that returns the main page, `index.html`. However, when I remove the line

```
requestpath += options.index
```

I get the following error:

```
500: encountered error while processing GET of "/"
```

Without that line, wouldn't the request be `localhost:3000/`, which should serve `index.html`?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `fs.exist` function at the end, but I'm not sure.

```
var return_index = function (request, response, requestpath) {
    var exists_callback = function (file_exists) {
        if (file_exists) {
            return serve_file(request, response, requestpath);
        } else {
            return respond(request, response, 404);
        }
    }
    if (requestpath.substr(-1) !== '/') {
        requestpath += "/";
    }
    requestpath += options.index;
    return fs.exists(requestpath, exists_callback);
}
```

`options` is equal to

```
{
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    index: "index.html",
    docroot: "."
}
```

Comment: In what context, is this Node.js, and what does `requestpath` do? It looks like the difference would be absolute and relative paths

Comment: And what is `options.index`? Can you `console.log(options.index);` and tell us what it returns?

Comment: yes it is node.js. I will update the post with option.index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.exists` checks whether a file exists in the file system. Since `requestpath += options.index` is changing `/` to `/index.html`, without it `fs.exists` will not find a file. (`/` is a directory, not a file, hence the error.)

This may seem confusing since `localhost:3000/` should serve `index.html`. On the web, `/` is shorthand for `index.html` (unless you have the default file set to something else). When you ask for `/`, the file system looks for `index.html` and, if it exists, serves it.

I would change your code to:

```
var getIndex = function (req, res, path)  {    
    if (path.slice(-1) !== "/")
        path += "/";
    path += options.index;
    return fs.exists(path, function (file) {
        return file ? serve_file(req, res, path) : respond(req, res, 404);
    });
}
```

Try and make callbacks anonymous, unless you know you're going to use them elsewhere. Above, `exists_callback` was only going to be used once, so save some code and pass it as an anonymous function. Also, in node.js, you should use `camelCase` and not underscores, e.g., `getIndex` over `return_index`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that requestpath maps uri to file system - but it is not pointing to a specific file(ex: http://localhost/ maps to /myrootpath/). What you want to do is to serve default file from that folder (ex: index.html) which I think is stored in options.index. That's why you have to append options.index to the path.